Error converting string to byte[] in c# DataTable
I am reading in .csv data from various files into a C# DataTable object, respectively. As it is .csv, I am reading all data as string initially. Afterwards I want to write it to a SQL Server table using SqlBulkCopy class.
I need to convert the columns to the target data type in the destination and wanted to do it like this by implicitly letting DataTable doing the conversion:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;

namespace SQLBulkTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable("dt");

            DataColumn item = new DataColumn("item", typeof(String));
            dt.Columns.Add(item);

            DataColumn type = new DataColumn("type", typeof(String));
            dt.Columns.Add(type);

            DataColumn bin = new DataColumn("bin", typeof(String));
            dt.Columns.Add(bin);

            DataColumn floatItem = new DataColumn("floatItem", typeof(String));
            dt.Columns.Add(floatItem);

            // Add five items.
            DataRow NewRow;
            var teststring = "0x0050568F00041ED783A79F94B797E9B6";

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                NewRow = dt.NewRow();
                NewRow["item"] = i.ToString();
                NewRow["type"] = "Type " + i;
                NewRow["bin"] = teststring;
                NewRow["floatItem"] = i.ToString() + "," + i.ToString();
                dt.Rows.Add(NewRow);
            }

            DataTable dtCloned = dt.Clone();
            dtCloned.Columns[0].DataType = typeof(Int32);
            dtCloned.Columns[2].DataType = typeof(System.Byte[]);
            dtCloned.Columns[3].DataType = typeof(double);

            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                var mappedRow = dt.NewRow();
                mappedRow[0] = row[0];
                mappedRow[1] = row[1];
                mappedRow[2] = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes((string)row[0]);
                mappedRow[3] = row[3];
                dtCloned.Rows.Add(mappedRow.ItemArray);
            }
        }
    }
}

When running the code I get the following error:

System.ArgumentException: 'Type of value has a mismatch with column typeCouldn't store <System.Byte[]> in bin column. Expected type is Byte[].'

What could I do to also import binary data? In SQL Server, it needs to be stored as varbinary.

as @Steve pointed out, there was an error in the code and it works out when following his guidance

There is an error in your code.
You should create the mappedRow from the dtCloned table. Because this one is the DataTable with the Byte[] column datatype
var mappedRow = dtCloned.NewRow();

Also there is no need to pass the ItemArray when you add the new row to the dtCloned table. You could just use mappedRow
dtCloned.Rows.Add(mappedRow);


correctly spotted, will change this and retry
